# CSSTransition:- React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

Below in my code. `CSSTransition` is not being recognized. It throws an error for some reason. I tried importing with and without braces, but it didn't seem to work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from '../stylesheets/style.module.css';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
class SlideShow extends Component {
  state = {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    changePic: true,
    slideIndex: 1,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.slideshowContainer}>
        <CSSTransition
          in={this.state.changePic}
          timeout={{
            enter: 2000,
            exit: 800,
          }}
          classNames="slidePics"
          unmountOnExit={true}
        ></CSSTransition>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SlideShow;
```

Comment: what exactly error does it throw?

Comment: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.  - it says that . and when i remove CSSTransition, it works fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Make sure to actually install `react-transition-group`
2. Import without curly braces

Comment: actually i am getting a new error, while using  CSSTransition. Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

Comment: sounds like there should be something inside your <CSSTransition/>. In your case it's empty as far as I can see